# List non empty directories

Tags: r

Is there any easy way to list only directories that are not empty?

I am aware of `list.dirs` but I couldn't find the way to list only directories that are not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list.files` on the result of `list.dirs`:

```
dirlist <- list.dirs("./R/R-3.3.1/library/zoo")
dirlist [sapply(dirlist, function(x) length(list.files(x))>0)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Get filenames then extract directory name:

```
unique(dirname(list.files(full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner solution:

```
nonempty <- list.dirs(recursive=F)[which(lengths(lapply(list.dirs(recursive=F), list.files)) > 0)]
```

Comment: True - i just microbenchmarked it, and storing the non-recursive `list.dirs()` in a variable shaves a mean ~1.8 milliseconds for 100 runs. The OP can choose to use a two-liner for improved efficiency.